# Cannot return C struct in C++ code with namespace in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

Cython version is 0.21.1

I want to return C struct data in C++ code with namespace.

I got a compile error

```
error: ‘__pyx_convert__to_py_Test’ has not been declared
```

Cannot I use C struct in C++ code with namespace in Cython?
What is this prefix(__pyx_convert__to_py_Test)?

Cython generates a code like this:

```
static PyObject* __pyx_convert__to_py_Test::mydata(struct Test::mydata s);
```

Note that when I build the code without namespace, the problem doesn't happen.

Here is a example code:

libmy.h

```cpp
namespace Test {
    struct mydata {
        int id;
        char name[256];
    };
    class Myclass {
        mydata _data;
    public:
        const mydata & get_data() const;
    };
}
```

libmy.cpp

```
namespace Test {
    const mydata & Myclass::get_data() const {
        return const_cast<const mydata&>(_data);
    }
}
```

test.pxd

```
cdef extern from "libmy.h" namespace "Test":
    cdef struct mydata:
        int id
        char* name

    cdef cppclass Myclass:
        const mydata & get_data()
```

test.pyx

```
cimport test as my

cdef class Py_Myclass:
    cdef my.Myclass *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new my.Myclass()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def get_data(self):
        return <const mydata&>self.thisptr.get_data()
```

setup.py

```
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("mylib", ["mylib.pyx"], language="c++", libraries=["my"])])
)
```

When I use 'cppclass' instead of 'struct' in test.pxd, I got a different error.

```
Cannot convert 'mydata const  &' to Python object
```

I change

```
cdef struct mydata:
```

to

```
cdef cppclass mydata:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by myself.
I should create a python object contains C++ struct information in 'test.pyx' file.

For example

```
def get_data(self):
    d = self.thisptr.get_data()
    data = {}
    data["id"] = d.id
    data["name"] = d.name
    return data
```

I also changed C struct to 'cppclass' in 'test.pxd' file.

```
 cdef cppclass mydata:
    int id
    char* name
```